# Trouble reading jar resources from android

Tags: java, android, jar

Setup:

1. dictionaryUtil.jar - contains single class and a folder with dictionary files. There is main method which serves as a simple test driver for its functionality.
2. TestDriver.java - standalone class that is used to test functionality of jar in standalone mode (outside of android). It only has one line: "DictionaryUtil.main(null);" - THIS WORKS
3. MainActivity.java - test android application which simply does the same thing as the TestDriver, but within the onCreate() within android. The only line: "DictionaryUtil.main(null);" THIS DOES NOT WORK. (returns NPE from within DictionaryUtil due to the below)

The problem is the call to getResource() while running inside of android returns null:

- URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("shortlist"); //the folder inside of the jar
- URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(dictionaryUtil.jar);//the jar name

The above code is inside of DictionaryUtil.main(), which works in standalone mode and returns null while run within the app. The jar is being read, as it executes the DictionaryUtil class, but it cannot get the resources. Even when I put the above code snippets (a, b) directly into my onCreate() method, I get the same result. I'm at a loss here.